# SWIG: Using std::map accessors with a shared_ptr?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm experiencing an odd issue with a SWIG-generated Python wrapper to a C++ class, wherein I cannot seem to use the standard accessor functions of `std::map` when it is wrapped as a `std::shared_ptr` type. I managed to produce a MWE that reproduces the odd behavior I am observing.

**TestMap.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class fooType{
  public:
  fooType() { };
  ~fooType() { };
  void printFoo() { std::cerr << "FOO!" << std::endl; }
  static std::shared_ptr<fooType> make_shared() { 
      return std::shared_ptr<fooType>(new fooType()); 
  }
};

class testMap : public std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<fooType> > {
  public:
   void printBar() { std::cerr << "bar." << std::endl; }
};
```

And then my SWIG interface file:

**TestMap.i**

```
%module TestMap

%include <std_map.i>
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>

%{
#include "TestMap.h"
%}

%shared_ptr(fooType);
%shared_ptr(testMap);
%shared_ptr(std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<fooType> > );

%template(fooMap) std::map< int, std::shared_ptr<fooType> >;

%include "TestMap.h"
```

Finally, the test script I'm using to test out the interface:

**test_interface.py**

```
import TestMap as tm

ft = tm.fooType.make_shared()
myTestMap = tm.testMap()

myTestMap[1] = ft
```

As-written, I get the following error when I try to use the map accessor:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_interface.py", line 9, in <module>
    myTestMap[1] = ft
  File "/home/sskutnik/tstSWIG/TestMap.py", line 217, in __setitem__
    return _TestMap.fooMap___setitem__(self, *args)
 NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'fooMap___setitem__'.
   Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
     std::map< int,std::shared_ptr< fooType > >::__setitem__(std::map< int,std::shared_ptr< fooType > >::key_type const &)
     std::map< int,std::shared_ptr< fooType > >::__setitem__(std::map< int,std::shared_ptr< fooType > >::key_type const &,std::map< int,std::shared_ptr< fooType > >::mapped_type const &
```

When I check the type of `ft` and `myTestMap`, both are `std::shared_ptr` references of their respective classes:

```
<TestMap.fooType; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< fooType > *' at 0x7fa812e80a80> >
<TestMap.testMap; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< testMap > *' at 0x7fa812e80c90> >
```

Now for the odd part - if I omit the `%shared_ptr(TestMap)` declaration from my SWIG interface file and recompile, the map accessor (in **test_interface.py**) happily works. When I check the type of `myTestMap`, it's:

```
<TestMap.testMap; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'testMap *' at 0x7f8eceb50630> >
```

So, two questions:

1. Why does my accessor call work correctly when I have a SWIG object pointer reference (`testMap*`), but not when I have a `shared_ptr` reference (e.g., `std::shared_ptr< testMap > *`)?
2. How do I get around this, given that I need a `shared_ptr` for my derived map type?

**Bonus question:** why does SWIG automatically convert `testMap*` into a `std::shared_ptr<testMap>` type if I declare the existence of a `shared_ptr` type for the `testMap` type (even if it's not initialized as such?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time `myTestMap = tm.testMap()` creates an transparent shared_ptr. So `myTestMap[1]` is a transparent dereferencing of the shared_ptr with subsequent assignment of the value to the key.
Second time `myTestMap = tm.testMap()` creates empty std::map, so `myTestMap[1]` is assignment of a value to the the `key=1` of the map.

`%shared_ptr(testMap)` is semantically similar to `%template(testMap) shared_ptr<testMap>`. `%template(testMapPtr) shared_ptr<testMap>` will create a new shared_ptr type `testMapPtr`, which holds NULL initially  (see the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)), so `testMapPtr[1]` would dereference a NULL value yielding some exception.
**Update:** `%shared_ptr(testMap)` creates a fully transparent shared_ptr initialized with the testMap default constructor.

Comment: As for the "Bonus question": `%shared_ptr(testMap)` is the same as `%template(testMap) shared_ptr<testMap>`. Use `%template(testMapPtr) shared_ptr<testMap>` to avoid such change of the testMap semantics.

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me for the most part. What I did notice is that even if I created a method to explicitly create a non-null shared_ptr for testMap, I got the same issue.

However, I noticed that when I separated out the definition of testMap from the shared pointer template (e.g., `%template(testMapPtr) std::shared_ptr<testMap>`, I instead got the (helpful) error that the item assignment operator is not supported.

Separating out the smart pointer template from the base class and then using an alternate function when I have to have a smart pointer type works. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that the answer is helpful! And a minor correction for my explanation: `%template(testMapPtr) shared_ptr<testMap>` results in initially empty `testMapPtr` shared pointer, but `%shared_ptr(testMap)` actually creates a transparent shared_ptr, which is already initialized with the `testMap` instance.  I will add it to the answer.